# UIViewController doesn't adjust content insets when shown by another UIViewController (within a UINavigationController)

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, uitextview, uiedgeinsets

I have a navigation controller whose root is a view controller (call it First). This First view controller has a button that, when pressed, shows another view controller (call it Second). This Second view controller has a single UITextView that covers the whole view.

In the storyboard, the sample text in the UITextView correctly starts below (but not underneath) the title bar. In other words, its content insets are set correctly.

However, when I run the app and I tap on the First view controller's button in order to show the Second view controller, the text is underneath the title bar. The text view's content insets are zero.

Why isn't the text view's top content inset automatically adjusted to account for the title bar?

I've created a "minimum" app that shows the problem: https://github.com/redcurry/TestContentInsets.

Note: I'm using Xamarin, but I imagine the same problem happens in iOS (I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 0):

In the second View Controller please uncheck the "Adjust ScrollView Insets" check box.[image: Please see the screenshot]

Comment: That didn't work. The text view is still underneath the navigation title bar.

Comment: Could you please try out by adjusting the top constraint of textView

Comment: Adjusting it to what?

Comment: if you make the top constraint of text view (top space) to be 0 with the top layout guide. If you increase the top space i.e a value > 0 then it will subsequently come down.
Please don't forget to give other constraints for text view(like trailing space, leading,bottom spaces or height ) according to your design

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this

Your view is starting from under the navigationController.
You just need to set this.

[image]

Comment: let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Text is still underneath the navigation title bar.

Comment: sorry , i wont be able to help with xamarin,

Comment: i used to apply the above solution for issue like this in native.